# How to style WTForm field through a widget?

Tags: widget, wtforms

I want to style a wtform field through a [custom widget](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/widgets.html#custom-widgets) but the rendering keeps returning raw html code (with ampersands). Why?

this is my widget:

```
def my_widget(field, **kwargs):
    field_id = kwargs.pop('id', field.id)
    html = [u'<input class="my_class" %s value="" type="text">' % html_params(id=field_id, name=field_id)]
    return u''.join(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell than string should be rendered as is without escaping HTML:

```
from wtforms.widget.core import HTMLString

def my_widget(field, **kwargs):
    ....
    return HTMLString(u''.join(html))
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, I had to do:

`from wtforms.widgets.core import HTMLString`

there was probably a renaming somewhere along the line.